# How to get selective data from file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to get selective data from a textfile with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWHCt.png) content. I am using the following code to read in the fourth column:

```
fid = fopen('class.txt');
C = textscan(fid, '%*s %*s %*s %f %*[^\n]');
C = C{:};
```

I want to get the values in the first column only when the corresponding value of the fourth column is equal to `1`. I want to execute the code below where the value of `C=1` so that I can get only selective data from file.

```
R = textscan(fid, '%f %*[^\n]');
R = R{:};
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading in the whole file and then extract the rows where the fourth column equals to `1` in a second step. The following code gets the needed columns as a cell array `data`, then assigns the contents of the cells to `R` and `C`. Now you can use logical indexing to only get the desired rows.

```
fid = fopen('class.txt');
data = textscan(fid, '%f %*s %*s %f');
R = data{1};
C = data{2};

result = R(C==1)
```

---

For the dataset...

```
14 114 214 0
15 115 214 0
17 117 215 1
18 118 216 1
15 113 214 1
```

... the output is the following:

```
result =
    17
    18
    15
```

Comment: @Rio Consider accepting the answer if it answers your question sufficiently enough.